# pdfminer when I am trying to run pdf2txt.py not working in windows

Tags: python, windows, pdf, pdfminer, pdf2htmlex

I have installed pdfminer and when I am trying to run

```
pdf2txt.py test.pdf -t html -o test.html
```

no error showing and command also not executing in windows.
Please help me how can i convert true pdf files in html file.

Thanks.

Comment: On windows?  I'm not positive, but I think you have to specify the `python.exe` as the first command argument.

Comment: If Windows doesn't recognize the `.py` extension there *will* be an error message: not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program of batch file.

Comment: @Tony thanks, as you said it is much positive,I have tried with python.exe but still it is not working.